# How to update gitlab Merge Request basic check status when using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, devops, jenkins-plugins, cicd

How to update GitLab Merge Request basic check status when using Jenkins pipeline?

Same as Github status plugin which show the code is ready to merge after all checks are passed.